# update solr documents after modifying schema.xml

Tags: solr

I juste changed 
 - my signature type from Lookup3Signature to TextProfileSignature and
 - the type of few fields from String to text_general
and then, I restarted solr. 
I would like to have old solr documents taking into consideration these changes. 
Is there a way to that without having to re-index everything? 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the schema, the change will only affect new documents indexed. You will need to re-index if you want new definition to take place for old data.

Comment: There is "update" feature, If you plan to update fields in
documents within Solr after they’re indexed (as opposed to resending the full documents from an external source) then you’ll need to store all fields so that Solr has a copy of the original content for each field.You can update existing documents in Solr by sending a new version of the document. But
unlike a database in which you can update a specific column in a row, with Solr you must update the entire document. Solr deletes the existing document and creates a new one; this occurs whether you change one field or all fields.

Comment: So in your case it is better to re-index. The "update" solr meant for is to re-index a specific field for few documents, say if you want to update price of a product , but nothing else changed you send in id and price, solr retrieves rest of the fields from the index , deletes the document and re-indexes the document with new price.